# Все ли существительные могут управлять инфинитивной конструкцией?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, грамматика, стилистика

Есть множество корректных выражений, в которых существительное сочетается с последующим инфинитивом: *мастер сказки рассказывать*, *любитель выпить* и т. п. Но всякое ли существительное может поставить в такое положение инфинитив? Вопрос возник в соседнем форуме для иностранцев. Там обсуждался пример "**на грани того, чтобы быть уволенным**": можно ли это выражение упростить до "(он находился) **на грани быть уволенным**"? Такое предложение поступило от носителя русского языка и было принято автором вопроса как более лаконичный вариант. Для меня это звучит неестественно, в отличие от напр. "**на грани** (пороге, рубеже) **увольнения**". На мой взгляд, без "*того, чтобы*" существуют смысловые ограничения для существительного: оно должно быть если не отглагольным, то хотя бы косвенно указывать на производителя действия (инфинитива). Например, "*нежелание быть уволенным*" - сочетание безупречное ("нежелание" относится к человеку, который "не желает быть").

А как вы воспринимаете "находится на грани быть(/сделать/стать)..."? Есть ли какие-либо материалы с формальной рекомендацией оценки сочетаемости существительного с инфинитивом в  подобных конструкциях?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что сочетание "на грани быть уволенным" недопустимо в русском языке.

> Есть ли какие-либо материалы с формальной рекомендацией оценки
>   сочетаемости существительного с инфинитивом в подобных конструкциях?

В Гугле можно найти работы, затрагивающие этот вопрос. Для примера приведу цитату из [одной такой работы](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/74362/62-Filtsova.pdf?sequence=1).

> Рассматривая случаи сочетаемости инфинитива с существительным, В. М. Брицын подчёркивает их 
>   избирательный характер (при свободе лексического заполнения позиции инфинитива наблюдаются строгие 
>   ограничения на выбор существительного) и отрицает возможность составления сколько-нибудь точного 
>   словника имён, сочетающихся с инфинитивом, поскольку имеется довольно большое количество случаев, 
>   «когда необходимо разграничивать явления нормы и узуса, узуса и индивидуального словоупотребления» (отметим, что для изучающего русский язык как неродной такая ситуация заведомо исключается, 
>   в силу её неоднозначности). Чаще всего наблюдаются случаи употребления инфинитива: 
>   1) с сущ. типа любитель, охотник, сторонник со значением «склонный к чему-л.»;
>   2) с  некоторыми  группами  отглагольных  сущ.  (попытка,  старание,  жажда,  желание,  замысел, намерение,  план,  боязнь,  волнение,  привычка,  клятва,  обещание и  т.п.);  
>   3) при  сущ.,  соотносимых  с прилагательными (безнадёжность,  мудрость,  наглость...)
>   и,  наконец, 
>   4) при  сущ.,  не  соотносимых  с другими частями речи (среди них сущ. с семами «способ, возможность, право, система взглядов, традиция, время,  предназначение,  устремление»).

В списке литературы указана монография Брицина, возможно, в ней можно найти более подробную информацию.

Comment: Спасибо, мне вчера не удалось найти источники. Сегодня попался вот такой заумный: http://e.lib.vlsu.ru/bitstream/123456789/2426/1/01130.pdf (Могография Варюшенковой СИНТАКСИЧЕСКИЕ ФУНКЦИИ ПРИСУБСТАНТИВНОГО ИНФИНИТИВА В ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИИ) Но некоторые смежные вопросы мне там показались излишне либерально трактуемыми, например принимается как допустимое (прецедент у О.Форш) глагольно-инфинитивное сочетание "не искал выделиться" - недавно у нас рассматривалось странное "искал сказать".

Comment: @Alex_ander Ваша ссылка получше будет и поинтереснее; нравится.

Answer (score 1):

**На грани быть уволенным** ― это неверное сочетание. Здесь дело прежде всего в **устойчивой** форме ***на грани***.

**На грани чего-л.** В непосредственной близости к переходу в другое (обычно худшее) состояние. На грани войны, катастрофы. На грани безумия. Этот вид животных на грани исчезновения.

Можно сказать:  **на грани увольнения**. Событие в этом случае обозначено **отглагольным существительным.**

А вот другие существительные могут сочетаться с ***быть уволенным***, например: **возможность** быть уволенным, **судьба** быть уволенным.

**Эта тема подробно дается в Грамматике-80** (у меня бумажная книга "Краткая русская грамматика" под ред. Шведовой и Лопатина, 1990 год, § 420. **Примыкание инфинитива**).

Там рассмотрено примыкание инфинитива **к глаголам, прилагательным и существительным.**

Обычно **существительные** воспроизводят **связи глаголов и прилагательных**: стремиться уехать ― стремление уехать, способный бороться ― способность бороться.

Круг таких существительных может расширяться за счет **синонимических связей**: **судьба** (возможность) остаться, **талант** (способность) сочинять.

**Другие варианты:**

а) пора ехать, время идти ― временное значение предстояния.

б) мастер говорить, любитель пошутить ― качественное значение (соотнесенность с прилагательными).

Comment: Спасибо. Хорошо, что об этом пишут и в рапространённых источниках.

Comment: Тут дело даже не в распространенных источниках, а в базовых основах грамматики. Язык, конечно, развивается, но все грамматические новшества желательно соотносить с основами этой науки, изложенными в академических учебниках.